# $apply already in progress without using $apply anywhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following javascript code:

```
$scope.fav_details = function(id1,id2,bio) {
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(id1).style.display="block";
    $scope.getLegislatorDetails(bio);
    document.getElementById(bio).click();
}
```

The line that is throwing the following error is the click event above.
What I dont understand is that I did not apply $apply anywhere in my code still I am getting this error. Can someone help me. The getLegislatorDetails function in the above code has an api call and stores the data in a scope variable.
I have the following angular js error:

```
angular.js:13642 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:6:412
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:137:381)
    at m.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:312)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:274:247)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (http://localhost/congress/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10315)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (http://localhost/congress/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8342)
    at m.$scope.fav_details (http://localhost/congress/scripts.js:938:38)
    at fn (eval at compile (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:231:126), <anonymous>:4:436)
    at b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:126:19)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13642
angular.js:13642 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:6:412
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:137:381)
    at m.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:142:30)
    at m.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:401)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:274:247)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (http://localhost/congress/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10315)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (http://localhost/congress/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8342)
    at m.$scope.fav_details (http://localhost/congress/scripts.js:938:38)
    at fn (eval at compile (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:231:126), <anonymous>:4:436)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13642
```

The getLegislatorDetails function can be found in the following link:-

https://github.com/anirbanmishra/congress.php/blob/master/getLegislatorDetails

Comment: I'm assuming this is code within a controller. You shouldn't do DOM manipulation within a controller. Can you show us the `$scope.lgetLegislatorDetails` code?

Comment: Yes the above code is inside an controller...and the getLegislatorDetails function can be found in:- https://github.com/anirbanmishra/congress.php/blob/master/getLegislatorDetails

Comment: @NexusDuck any clue??

Comment: document.getElementById(bio).click(); what are you trying to achieve with this ? I suggest remove this and directly call what ever the  ckick function is

Answer (score 0):

In case you attached

```
ng-click=getLegislatorDetails
```

For bio element

then comment any line from below code

```
  $scope.getLegislatorDetails(bio);
        document.getElementById(bio).click();
```